# OLS regression with explanatory variables of different length

Tags: regression

I have calculated returns from the Betting Against Beta strategy from 1926 until 2012 and want to take an OLS regression with Mkt-RF, HML, SMB, MOM and liquidity factors as independent variables. The problem is that data for the liquidity data starts in 1968. Will I have to start the regression from 1968, or is there a way to include the LIQ factor from 1968? I am coding in Python

Answer (score 0):

You can add new binary variable to indicate when the data is populated and when it is not. If you use 1 when the data is absent and set the missing data to 0 this can create an adjustment term. You could also replace the data with an estimate though this would introduce bias. [Here is a general guide](https://machinelearningmastery.com/binary-flags-for-missing-values-for-machine-learning/)

This might have some consequences with regard to the assumptions behind OLS regression so you'll want to make extra make extra sure these hold with your dataset to be confident drawing conclusions. The assumptions are well laid out [here](https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/ols-linear-regression-assumptions/#:%7E:text=OLS%20Assumption%201%3A%20The%20regression,coefficients%20and%20the%20error%20term&text=In%20the%20equation%2C%20the%20betas,the%20parameters%20that%20OLS%20estimates.&text=Linear%20models%20can%20model%20curvature,polynomials%20and%20transforming%20exponential%20functions.).